# Trying to make a discord bot, but it won't connect to discord

Tags: python, discord, bots

I've been scratching my head for hours and I can't seem to get my bot to connect to discord, I'm using this code for the bot:

```
import os

import discord
from dotenv import load_dotenv

load_dotenv()
TOKEN = os.getenv('DISCORD_TOKEN')

client = discord.Client()

@client.event
async def on_ready():
print(f'{client.user} has connected to Discord!')

client.run(TOKEN)
```

and this one for the .env file

```
DISCORD_TOKEN = "token here"
```

and yet, this error keeps on running:

```
    Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\amber\OneDrive\Desktop\Python39\MemeBot\MemeBot.py", line 16, in <module>
    client.run(TOKEN)
  File "C:\Users\amber\AppData\Local\Packages\PythonSoftwareFoundation.Python.3.9_qbz5n2kfra8p0\LocalCache\local-packages\Python39\site-packages\discord\client.py", line 723, in run
    return future.result()
  File "C:\Users\amber\AppData\Local\Packages\PythonSoftwareFoundation.Python.3.9_qbz5n2kfra8p0\LocalCache\local-packages\Python39\site-packages\discord\client.py", line 702, in runner
    await self.start(*args, **kwargs)
  File "C:\Users\amber\AppData\Local\Packages\PythonSoftwareFoundation.Python.3.9_qbz5n2kfra8p0\LocalCache\local-packages\Python39\site-packages\discord\client.py", line 665, in start
    await self.login(*args, bot=bot)
  File "C:\Users\amber\AppData\Local\Packages\PythonSoftwareFoundation.Python.3.9_qbz5n2kfra8p0\LocalCache\local-packages\Python39\site-packages\discord\client.py", line 511, in login
    await self.http.static_login(token.strip(), bot=bot)
AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'strip'
```

I'm stumped, any help would be greatly appreciated :)

Comment: `DISCORD_TOKEN` is not found in the environment, so `os.getenv('DISCORD_TOKEN')` is returning None.

Comment: I tried to fix it by removing the quotes in the code for os.getenv('DISCORD_TOKEN') so it would be os.getenv(DISCORD_TOKEN) but instead got this :(


`Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\amber\OneDrive\Desktop\Python39\MindfulBot\MindfulBot.py", line 8, in <module>
    TOKEN = os.getenv(DISCORD_TOKEN)
NameError: name 'DISCORD_TOKEN' is not defined`

Answer (score 0):

**TL;DR: Have your `.env` file in the same or higher directory to your script**

---

The problem is that the discord library is trying to strip your token but it is a `None` type. So your environment variable is not loading correctly.

Make sure your `.env` file is located in the right place in the directory structure and is loading correctly. From the documentation: https://pypi.org/project/python-dotenv/

> By default, load_dotenv doesn't override existing environment
> variables.
>
> To configure the development environment, add a .env in the root
> directory of your project:
>
> ├── .env 
> └── foo.py

I was able to get your code working just by putting the `.env` file and python script in the same directory.

Comment: where do I find my root directory? Can you provide me a better example? I'm new to using dotenv

Comment: So you just want to have it in the same or a higher directory than the script. Because if I understand correctly dotenv will just search up the directory tree to find the nearest .env file.

Comment: Yeah, but how do I find and edit it and put the .env file in a higher directory than the script

Comment: I'm using Python 3.9 btw if that affects anything

Comment: So look at where the file is that contains the code:

`import os

import discord
from dotenv import load_dotenv

load_dotenv()
TOKEN = os.getenv('DISCORD_TOKEN')

client = discord.Client()

@client.event
async def on_ready():
print(f'{client.user} has connected to Discord!')

client.run(TOKEN)`

Put the `.env` file that you wrote in the same directory as that file. Your code file.